# What does texspace_location and texspace_size mean? in the blender Mesh Data

Tags: python

so I was looking through [here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh)

and two of the mesh properties are texspace_location and texspace_size?

i was assuming these were uv coordinates and the scale of the uv map, but there are three floats in each one.

am i correct in my assumption, or am i way off?

also if they are uv coordinates what does the third float in each one mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with UV, it transforms texture space (for box mapping etc.). Turn on Texture Space to see it:

[image]

And in Outliner in datablocks view under meshes>your_mesh if you turn off *Auto Texture Space* you can fiddle with the values and see what they do:

[image]

Comment: thanks, so if i'm looking for the uv coordinates, where would i find them? like say bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data... what would be the rest?

Comment: By accessing the face.loops in bmesh mesh. Search if it is not answered yet and if not put it as new question.)